# using CSOM to retrieve fields in a list in a view

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

I am trying to use the CSOM to retrieve all the displayed fields in a particular view.

I require to know the field type and field internal name.

I can not do:

```
var list = hostWebContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('any list');
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("All Items");
fieldsInView = view.get_viewFields();
context.load(fieldsInView);
context.executeQueryAsync(onListSuccess, OnListFail);
```

Because .get_viewFields() only get the internal name and not the field type.. So what I have done is first I will get all the fields in a list, and also the fields in a view and iterate through the fields in the list and check if it also in the view, if it is, ill add it to my array.

This is what I have so far:

```
function getList() {
    var hostWebContext = new SP.AppContextSite(context, decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl")));


    var list = hostWebContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('any list');
    var view = list.get_views().getByTitle("All Items");
    fields = list.get_fields();
    fieldsInView = view.get_viewFields();

    context.load(fields);
    context.load(fieldsInView);

    context.executeQueryAsync(onListSuccess, OnListFail);
}

function onListSuccess() {

    var fieldEnumerator = fields.getEnumerator();

    var fieldArray = new Array();

    while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        var fieldName = oField.get_internalName();



        if (!oField.get_hidden()) {
            var found = $.inArray(fieldName, fieldsInView) > -1;  // DOES NOT WORK!!


            var aField = {
                fieldName: fieldName,
                fieldType: oField.get_fieldTypeKind()
            };


            if (found) { fieldArray.push(aField); }
        }


    }

}
```

My problem here is this line:

```
var found = $.inArray(fieldName, fieldsInView) > -1
```

When I inspect the variable fieldsInView I find the values are actually in something like
fieldsInView.$2_0.$1_0[0]....

I could create another array and just use the command fieldsInView.getEnumerator() and and add the values to the new array, then handle it.. But this feels like double handling.

is there a better option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two considerations here:

1. The jQuery inArray function is implemented by calling the native Array indexOf function, if available, otherwise it uses a for loop to cycle through the array elements in search of a match.
2. Your current inArray call doesn't work because, as you've already realized, fieldsInView is a SPFieldCollection, which is an object that internally is really just an array of fields, but the array isn't part of the public API (any variable whose name starts with the $ sign is not meant to be used directly by client code, although, being javascript, nothing can stops you from accessing them, but it's not guaranteed that a future upgrade won't break your code, if you choose to do that).

Performance-wise, I wouldn't really care of first looping through the fieldsInView collection with the enumerator that you get from the getEnumerator function, in order to build an array of pure strings (fields internal names). Then I would use this newly built array as the second argument to the inArray function call. I think that the performance hit would be unnoticeable (how many fields you have in your view? If it some tenths, looping through them would take a fraction of a second).

Otherwise, you can use the [lodash library](http://lodash.com) _some function, which enables you to enumerate an array and passing each item to a callback function (which is your search match condition), but returns as soon as it finds a passing value and does not iterate over the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

[$.inArray function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) expects `Array` type to be passed, in your case `fieldsInView` variable is of `SP.ViewFieldCollection` type. 
So, in order to use `fieldsInView` in `$.inArray` it should be transformed into an Array, for example:

```
//Convert collection into array 
function collectionToArray(collection)
{
    var items = [];
    var e = collection.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) {
       var item = e.get_current();
       items.push(item);                
    }
    return items;
}
```

Example:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var view = list.get_views().getByTitle(viewTitle);
var fieldsInView = view.get_viewFields();
context.load(fieldsInView);
var fields = list.get_fields();
context.load(fields);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
      var fieldsNames = collectionToArray(fieldsInView); //get field names array 

      var fieldEnumerator = fields.getEnumerator();
      var fieldArray = new Array();
      while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var field = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        var fieldName = field.get_internalName();
        var found = $.inArray(fieldName, fieldsNames) > -1;
        //The remaining code is ommited for a clarity

      } 


    },
    function(sender,args){
          console.log(args.get_message());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're enumerating through all the fields anyways why not just try something like this:

```
var internalNames = [];
var types = [];
var viewFieldEnum = viewFields.getEnumerator();
while (viewFieldEnum.moveNext()) {
  var currentViewField = viewFieldEnum.get_current();
  var allFieldsEnum = fields.getEnumerator();
  while (allFieldsEnum.moveNext()) {
    var currentField = allFieldsEmum.get_current();
    if (currentViewField === currentField.get_internalName()) {
      internalNames.push(currentField.get_internalName());
      types.push(currentField.get_fieldTypeKind());
    }
  }
}
```

It may not be the prettiest thing ever written, but would this work for you? Should get you the field internal names and their types.