# Getting List Column Order

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-object-model

I'm using the SharePoint 2013 JavaScript APIs, calling `web.get_lists().getByTitle('ListTitle')` and then `list.get_fields()` to create a custom search panel. However, the fields do not come back based on the column ordering set in the list settings. Is there a way to get to the column order value via JavaScript? I've seen examples for setting, but none for reading it.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such property in field object, fields are sorted in List Settings page *by title if Content Types are enabled* as demonstrates the following example.

**Example**

```
function getListFields(listTitle,success,failure)
{
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
     var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle); 
     var fields = list.get_fields()
     ctx.load(fields);
     ctx.load(list);
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            var listFields = [];
             for(var i = 0; i < fields.get_count();i++) {
                 var field = fields.get_item(i);
                 if(field.get_hidden() == false && field.get_typeAsString() != 'File' 
                    && field.get_typeAsString() != 'Computed' && field.get_typeAsString() != 'Counter' 
                    || (field.get_typeAsString() == 'Lookup' && field.get_readOnlyField() != true)) {
                    listFields.push(field);   
                 }
            }
            if(list.get_contentTypesEnabled())
               listFields.sort(fieldComparer); //sort fields
            success(listFields);
        },
        failure);
}


function fieldComparer(x,y) {
  if (x.get_title() < y.get_title())
     return -1;
  if (x.get_title() > y.get_title())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Usage

```
getListFields('Pages',
function(fields){
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length;i++) {
        console.log(fields[i].get_title());
    }
},
function(sender,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

P.S. In the provided example the fields of type Computed, File and Counter are excluded since they are not displayed in List Settings page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would need to get the View for the lists, rather than the columns of the list. That way the ordering will be in place.

Look here:  [using CSOM to retrieve fields in a list in a view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92681/using-csom-to-retrieve-fields-in-a-list-in-a-view)

Comment: Thank you dotsa.  That could work. I was hoping to not have to rely on a view but rather get the values from the list settings column order. But if there are no other suggestions I will go that route. Appreciate the link to the sample.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I ended up creating a view on each list (configSearch) I am building dynamic advanced filtering for. The view allows me/user to layout the fields in any order and accommodate the adding of new fields to the search pane as the list grows. When a user select a list to search, I pass the list name to the following function. Once the data is returned I get the order from the view fields and the field details from list fields. Having that data I implement rendering logic for each field type (not included here). Later filtering is done using CamlJs (codeplex - not included here).

```
function getListFields(listnm) {
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listnm);
this.searchlist = list;
this.listFields = list.get_fields();
this.configFields = list.get_views().getByTitle("configSearch").get_viewFields();
clientContext.load(this.searchlist);
clientContext.load(this.listFields);
clientContext.load(this.configFields);    
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
    this.onListFieldsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, 
    this.onListFieldsQueryFailed));
}

function onListFieldsQuerySucceeded() {
var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
var fields = [];
while (fieldEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var listField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
    if (listField.get_hidden() || (listField.get_schemaXml().indexOf('http://') > -1 && listField.get_staticName().indexOf('Title') === -1))//skip sys fields
        continue;

    fields.push(listField);
    }

    $(window.configFields.get_data()).each(function (findex,fldIntNm) {//loop through view fields
        var oField = $(fields).filter( function () { if (this.get_internalName() == fldIntNm) return this; })[0];  //get field config info to help with rendering logic
             var fType = oField.get_fieldTypeKind();
             var fStaticName = oField.get_staticName();
             var fTitle = oField.get_title();
        //do more here - rendering logic
    });

});
}
```